# Differential equation math problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A particle is moving on a straight line in such a way that at each moment of time the product of its coordinate on the line and its acceleration is equal to the square of its velocity. Initially the particle positioned at the point with coordinate 1 on the line and has velocity 0.1. Find the position function of the particle.

How do I set up the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the position at time $t$. Then the velocity is $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and the acceleration is $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$. So the information we were given says that
$$x\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2.\tag{1}$$
To begin to solve the equation, let $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Then by the Chain Rule
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt},$$
and therefore (1) can be rewritten as
$$xv\frac{dv}{dx}=v^2.$$
I expect you can continue from here.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems for me TP means find $x(t)$ rather than $v(x)$. Unless when you find $v(x)$ we can solve $\dot x=v(x)$

Comment: Yes, OP wants $x(t)$. After finding $v$ as a function of $x$, OP will still have a differential equation to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\frac{x(t)}{\dot{x}(t)}$ and differentiate it with respect to $t$.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x(t)}{\dot{x}(t)}\right) = \frac{\dot{x}(t)^2-x(t)\ddot{x}(t)}{\dot{x}(t)^2}$$

Based on the information you gave $\dot{x}(t)^2-x(t)\ddot{x}(t) = 0$. This implies $\frac{x(t)}{\dot{x}(t)}= C$ for some constant. You can take it from here on I guess.